# How to add \n and delete space from perl regular expression

Tags: perl, design-patterns

I tried to add \n to output from this source:

```
sub fileresult{
open my $file;
my @listOfFiles;

while (<$file>) {
  if (m/^\s+ (\w+)/x) {
    push @listOfFiles, $1;
  }
}
close $file;
open my $fh, '>', ".\input.txt" or die "Cannot open input.txt: $!";
print  $fh join "\n", "@listOfFiles";
}
close $fh;
```

Output is like:

```
A B C
```

I want to be like:

```
A
B
C
```

without space at the begining of word and end of the word.

Comment: You should not "fix" your question after it is answered so that question and answer no longer makes sense together.

Comment: oh sorry... i think that it'll be better when i correct source ... thanks for edit ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you don't want to substitute nothing and only match it, `m/^\s+ (\w+)/x` instead of `s/^\s+ (\w+)/x/`

Also I can't see the place where you print them, but you could insert newlines between items, like:

```
print join "\n", @listOfFiles;
```

or

```
do { local $" = "\n"; print "@listOfFiles" };
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed...
close $file;
open my $fh, '>', "input.txt" or die "Cannot open input.txt: $!";
print  $fh join "\n", "@listOfFiles";
}

Comment: @choroba: Restrict the scope of the change of that global variable. But looking your answer I think it has the same meaning.

Comment: @Birei" No, it has not: `perl -e 'do{$"=1};print $"'`

Comment: @choroba: You are right. Very surprising for me because I was convinced that it created a scope. Thank you.

Comment: @Birei: It creates a scopt, but `$"` is a global variable which ignores scope unless localized.

Comment: @choroba: Ok. I had confused myself because tested your example with a normal variable (`$c`) and also printed it, but it's the same case. It creates it global. It's with `my` when it goes out of scope. All clear already.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `print` in your sample code. How do you generate the output? My magic ball says you used

```
print "@listOfFiles";
```

which prints the members of the array separated by the special variable `$"`, see [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar). You can set it to newline to change the output:

```
{ local $" = "\n" ; print "@listOfFiles" }
```

Or, less obscure, you can use `join`:

```
print join "\n", @listOfFiles;
```

Comment: I tied it, like in source in article but nothing changed

Comment: when I tried to add there: push @listOfFiles, $1, $enter; and define $enter = "\n" it do it, but like that:
\n
\n space A
\n space B